# GoToWebinar Webhook Signature verification fails

Tags: laravel, sha256

I am trying to verify webhook signature for GoToWebinar webinar.created event.

Docs: https://developer.goto.com/guides/HowTos/08_HOW_webhooks/

My Middleware (Laravel):

```
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
       
        if (! $this->verifyGoToWebinarWebhookSignature($request)) {
            abort(401);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    private function verifyGoToWebinarWebhookSignature(Request $request):bool
    {
        return ($request->header('x-webhook-signature') == $this->calculateHmac($request));
    }

    private function calculateHmac(Request $request):string
    {
        $secret = '12345';
        $signature = $request->header('x-webhook-signature-timestamp');
        $payload = json_encode($request->all(), true);
        $signaturePayload = $signature . ':' . $payload;

        return base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $signaturePayload, $secret, true));
    }
```

The comparison always returns false. Tested on real data. Can't figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Was using the wrong secret, the API allows to create multiple secret keys but if you do not store them there is not way to match them to the x-webhook-secretkey-id in the request header.